# How to use Curry with js-cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, curry-currency-converter

I'm trying to incorporate Curry (http://curry.netyou.co.il/) with the js-cookie API (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), but I've hit a snag and none of my experimenting has worked so far. I have been able to store both the currency name and the rate into separate cookie values, and read them back onto the page, but I can't figure out how to re-initialize the curry function.

The option "base" doesn't seem to accept a variable, and I'm not versed in js/jQuery enough to figure out how to tell curry to use the cookie variable a different way. I've been able to use jQuery to read the currency name from the cookie and change the 'option' to 'selected', but that itself doesn't update the prices, and I also can't figure out how to chain a re-initialization of curry after that function. My code is as follows:

```
var savedRate = Cookies.get('site_rate');
var savedCurrency = Cookies.get('site_currency');

$('.currency-list').curry({
    target: '.ov-property-price',
    base:   'AED',
    customCurrency: {
        'AED': 1,
        'EUR': 0.25,
        'GBP': 0.17,            
        'AUD': 0.36,
        'CHF': 0.26,
        'CAD': 0.34,
        'INR': 17.25,
        'IRR': 8015.36
    },
    symbols: {
        'AED': 'AED ',
        'EUR': '€',
        'GBP': '₤',         
        'AUD': 'AU$ ',
        'CHF': 'CHF ',
        'CAD': 'CA$',
        'INR': '₹',
        'IRR': '﷼'
    }
});

$('.currency-list').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected'), // get selected currency
    rate = selected.data('rate'), // get currency rate
    currency = selected.val(); // get currency name

    Cookies.set('site_currency', currency);
    Cookies.set('site_rate', rate);
});

$('.currency-list option[value="' + savedCurrency + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Sorry to ask such a basic question, but I'm confident that an explanation would benefit many other people using this plugin.

Many thanks.

Comment: What does `typeof selected.data('rate')` returns? Be aware that `Cookies.set` 2.0.2 accepts only Object Literals and Arrays in the value, as documented. The rest should be all Strings.

Comment: It currently returns `number`.  Is that why I can't use `savedCurrency` within the base` option? Both cookie values seem to save, read and print fine, I just don't know how to pass it to the curry function.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should allow you to setup curry with your saved currency or a default starter currency.

```js
// Setup defaults if cookie returns nothing
var savedRate = Cookies.get('site_rate') || 1;
var savedCurrency = Cookies.get('site_currency') || 'AED';

// Save custom currency list
var customCurrency = {
        'AED': 1,
        'EUR': 0.25,
        'GBP': 0.17,            
        'AUD': 0.36,
        'CHF': 0.26,
        'CAD': 0.34,
        'INR': 17.25,
        'IRR': 8015.36
    };

/* Set rate for saved currency
 * If saved rate is the same as in the
 * customCurrency list there is no need for this stage */
customCurrency[savedCurrency] = savedRate;

// Setup curry with your saved rates
$('.currency-list').curry({
    target: '.ov-property-price',
    base:   savedRate,
    customCurrency: customCurrency,
    symbols: {
        'AED': 'AED ',
        'EUR': '€',
        'GBP': '₤',         
        'AUD': 'AU$ ',
        'CHF': 'CHF ',
        'CAD': 'CA$',
        'INR': '₹',
        'IRR': '﷼'
    }
});
```