# How to Save currency and rate in cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, currency-formatting, curry-currency-converter

I have implemented a plugin called [Curry - Currency](http://curry.netyou.co.il/demo/), this plugin allow me to convert the price of my products to any currency selected in the dropdown. Currently once the user access to the website or press F5 to refresh the page, the price will show as : `[undefined0]`, to get the price I have to select a currency in the dropdown.

What I would like to is once the user access to the website if he didn't set a preferred currency, the price of the products will be converted to the default currency which is `[USD].`

I have tried to achieved that by using  [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), but I'm still getting `[undefined0]` , below what I have tried to do:

```
<select id="convert"></select>

<div class="changeprice">$20</div>
```

.

```
$(function(){
    $('#convert').curry({
        target: '.price',
        change: true,
        base: 'USD',
        symbols: {
            'ILS' : '₪',
            'GBP' : '£',
            'INR' :'<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>'

        }
    }).change(function(){
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected'), // get selected currency
            rate = selected.data('rate'), // get currency rate
            currency = selected.val(); // get currency name
        Cookies.remove('site_currency', { path: '' });
        Cookies.remove('site_rate', { path: '' });
        Cookies.set('site_currency', currency, { expires: 7, path: '' });
        Cookies.set('site_rate', rate, { expires: 7, path: '' });
        console.log( currency, rate );
    });
});



$('document').ready(function() {

 var CookieSet = Cookies.get('site_currency')

 if (CookieSet == 'undefined') {
   savedRate = 1;
   savedCurrency = '$ USD';
   console.log('CookieSet Empty. Set to '+savedCurrency);
 }
 else {
  savedRate = Cookies.get('site_rate');
  savedCurrency = Cookies.get('site_currency');
  console.log('CookieSet readed from cookie. Saved Rate: '+savedRate+' Saved currency: '+savedCurrency);
 }

 $('#convert').val( savedCurrency );

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QE9V3/31/

Comment: You could try session/local storage

Comment: `CookieSet == 'undefined'` doesn't feel right.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález , ok it doesn't feel right .....but how can I make it right ? Should I replaced `'undefined'` by `'null'` ?

Comment: I've never used that library so I can't tell you how it works, but it doesn't make sense to assign special values to random strings. Why would you use a literal `'undefined'` text to determine whether a cookie is set? What if you want to store `'undefined'` as data? Does the library include documentation or some usage examples?

Comment: There is some explanation in the [demo](http://curry.netyou.co.il/demo/) page of the plugin, but I don't find a nice example how to use cookies with this plugin.

Comment: @Sirius Have you had a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31294700/how-to-use-curry-with-js-cookie

Comment: @hitautodestruct, I have already tried to do something with the code in that question , but it doesn't work :( . I will keep working on it all night.....hopefully I will make it work soon.

Comment: @Sirius You are using **two** plugins. You won't find usage information for  *js-cookie* in the *Curry* site...

Answer (score 1):

Right from the [js-cookie readme](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie):

> Read cookie:
>
> ```
> Cookies.get('name'); // => 'value'
> Cookies.get('nothing'); // => undefined
> ```

So this part of the code is clearly a typo:

```
if (CookieSet == 'undefined') {
}
```

... because you are not comparing against the [`undefined` global property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), you are comparing against a piece of text. In JavaScript, as in most other languages, you have identifiers (variables) and you have literal texts (strings):

```js
var foo = "Hello, World!";
console.log("foo", foo);
```

You should be doing this:

```
if (CookieSet === undefined) {
}
```

... or, if you are paranoid and you think some code may have ovewritten the `undefined` property, this:

```
if (typeof CookieSet === "undefined") {
}
```

And please note that here we do quote "undefined" because [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) does return strings.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm by no means stating that this is the only issue and getting it fixed will make your app work, but this is clearly a broken bit that needs tweaking.</sub>

Comment: With Firefox and Microsoft edge I don't get undefined. I'm only getting undefined with chrome. I'm running the website on my locale machine, do you think chrome have an issue with setting cookies on locale machine ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but cookies are bound to a host name (IP address or domain name). If you don't have a web server (Apache, IIS, whatever) or a proper host name, browsers can refuse to accept them.